# Why aren't definitions well formed formulas?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

Why aren't definitions well formed formulas? For instance, the definition of an additive inverse is: *"Let $x \in \Bbb Z$. Then the additive inverse of $x$ is $y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $x+y=0$"*.

Why not just say *"there is $y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $\forall x, \ x+y=0$. This $y$ is the additive inverse of $x$"*?

The bigger issue seems to me that every step in a proof needs to be a complete sentence (i.e. a well formed formula) but a definition does not seem to do that? Why? And is my own definition of additive inverse equivalent?

Comment: Wait, did you just say "there is an integer y such that for any x, x+y=0"? You should take a look at that.

Comment: Yeah I know -just pick y=-x :/ guess I overlooked that. So definitions cannot be complete sentences, but why? Where in the name of logic permits this??

Comment: Is the definition simply "for any y, y is an additive inverse iff for every x, x+y=0"? Suppose that makes a complete sentence.

Comment: Regarding your example, you are (quite) right : we have to define a (binary) predicate : $Add_i(x,y) \leftrightarrow (x+y=0)$. In order to say "**the** additive inverse of $x$" we have to prove *uniqueness* (i.e. $\forall y_1 \forall y_2 [Add_i(x,y_1) \land Add_i(x,y_2) \to y_1=y_2]$. If so, we can introduce a new *function* symbol $A_i(x) = y \leftrightarrow Add_i(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formal treatment of a mathematical theory, *definitions* **are** well formed formulae.

See [Theory of definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123312/theory-of-definitions) and [Semantics and Logical structure in Definitons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820673/semantics-and-logical-structure-in-definitons).

A definition in the first order language of *arithmetic* (with : $0, S, +, \times$) introduces a new symbol, like :

> $1$ (a *constant*), or
>
> $\le$ (a binary *predicate*).

We can define $\le$ with the formula :

> > $x \le y \leftrightarrow \exists z (y=x+z)$.